# Using a range to input data to a filename

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon. I have been running into an issue with this code. It works perfectly if I allow the excel workbook to open, and then close it using the `ActiveWorkbook.Close` function. If I comment the `.close`  function out, I get the runtime error. I would desire all workbooks to open and stay open.

```
Sub openwb1()
    Dim EPath As String, EFile As String, EMo As String, EVar As String, lastrow As Long, counter As Long, EFound As String

    lastrow = Worksheets("Opener").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For counter = 1 To lastrow

    EPath = "Q:\MY PATH\"
    EVar = Worksheets("Opener").Range("A" & counter).Value
    EMo = MonthName(DatePart("m", Now), True) & " " & DatePart("yyyy", Now) & "\"
    EFound = Dir(EPath & EVar & EMo & "*$*.xlsx")

    If EFound <> " " Then
       Workbooks.Open FileName:=EPath & EVar & EMo & "\" & EFound
       End If

    If Len(Dir(EPath & EVar & EMo, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir EPath & EVar & EMo
        End If

    'ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next counter
End Sub
```

Comment: The variable `counter` doesn't appear to be used inside the loop.
Try changing `EVar = Worksheets("Opener").Range("A1").Value` to `EVar = Worksheets("Opener").Range("A" & counter).Value`

Comment: Do you want `EVar = Worksheets("Opener").Range("A" & counter).Value` ?  Also, it's worth mentioning to fix your line to `lastrow = Worksheets("Opener").Cells(Worksheets("Opener").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: `EPath = EPath = "C:My path\"` should be `EPath = "C:\My path\"`

Comment: yes that is correct ashfix; however the result is the same. It opens the file path in A1 and the errors for the name is A2. It gives me subscript out of range error

Comment: Add some `debug.print` and it will become obvious where the weak link is.

Comment: my last row is showing false.. with the Debug.Print I am stumped.

Comment: Huh? Is column A what you want?

Comment: So what does Debug.Print(Worksheets("Opener").Cells(Worksheets("Opener").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) yield, or just Debug.Print(lastrow)?

Comment: You have multiple sheets??

Comment: No multiple sheets. 1 sheet. Several excel files that I am trying to open automatically

Comment: `MonthName(DatePart("m", Now), True) & " " & DatePart("yyyy", Now) & "\"` could be changed to `Format(Now, "mmm yyyy") & "\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

```
Sub openwb1()

    Dim EPath As String, EFile As String, EMo As String
    Dim EVar As String, lastrow As Long, counter As Long, EFound As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    lastrow = Worksheets("Opener").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'next two lines do not need to be inside the loop
    EPath = "Q:\MY PATH\"
    EMo = MonthName(DatePart("m", Now), True) & " " & DatePart("yyyy", Now) & "\"

    For counter = 1 To lastrow

        EVar = Worksheets("Opener").Range("A" & counter).Value

        If Len(Dir(EPath & EVar & EMo, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

            MkDir EPath & EVar & EMo

        Else
            'only check for a file if the source folder was found...
            EFound = Dir(EPath & EVar & EMo & "*$*.xlsx")

            If EFound <> "" Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=EPath & EVar & EMo & "\" & EFound)

                'do something with wb

                wb.Close False 'don't save changes?

            End If

        End If

    Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `EVar = Worksheets("Opener").Range("A" & counter).Value` to `EVar = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Opener").Range("A" & counter).Value`.

BTW, `lastrow = Worksheets("Opener").Cells(Worksheets("Opener").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` could be changed to `lastrow = Worksheets("Opener").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, because every worksheet in this workbook has the same `Rows.Count`.  You do not need to specify which worksheet to count.

Comment: I am sorry. That did not work. I have posted my results to this thread.