# Calling filepath from Excel sheet, Opening Multiple Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Removing info due to duplicate. please see

[Using a range to input data to a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889895/using-a-range-to-input-data-to-a-filename)

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: Also you're going to run into the problem that your Efile value is stating the file name is `*$*.xlsx` .  File names can't have an `*` in the file name.

Comment: Sorry for any difficulty; there is a $ in the file name. It works fine on file 1.

Comment: try adding `msgbox EPath & EVar & EMo` before the `MkDir` line and post the result here. As @mrbungle said, you can't have a `*` in the filename.

Comment: – 3-14159265358979323846264 , I did as you asked, used F8 to step through each call and the file path worked properly on every line. The box popped up, I said "ok" and the file opened. After removing the message box, the error came back. Why would it do that?

Comment: Why try to open the file first and *then* check to see if the parent folder exists?  Also, Workbooks.Open doesn't accept wildcards, so this isn't going to work...  Maybe you need to explain in a little more detail exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Why was my comment deleted? It's suddenly ok to ask duplicate questions on SO??? Not to mention, the other questions has _very telling_ information where OP states that `debug.print` shows `false` for `a2` which makes no sense/suggests pertinent info missing from question. But meh.

Comment: Sorry guys. New to this exchange. Was hoping for a solution. Not sure what is being asked of me. I keep seeing that people are discussing debugging and wild cards. As I stated, the code works do the first file and works properly with the message box indicating the full file path (with wild card). Can someone please assist with what I need to do to make this an effective discussion.

Comment: Edit your question to show the values in column A, the file names your looking for and which line is the error.  Subscript out of range suggests you're referencing something that does not exist.

Comment: Just answer this - are all of your file named exactly as "*$*.xlsx" ?  Or are they named something else ?  Typically (when using `Dir()`) an asterisk is a *wildcard* meaning "zero or more other characters".  You cannot pass wildcard filenames to `Open()`, and `*` cannot be part of an actual filename, so what you're trying to do here needs a full and complete explanation.  People will help you if you can explain what it is you want to do.

Comment: Tim, there are multiple files in the directory. The one I want to open has is named xxx_$_xxx.xsls. thr file name will change. The only constant is the dollar sign in the middle of the file.

Comment: For the third time.  On which line is the error?  For me testing it without the open file this works through the cells.

Comment: mr bungle, It is saying that there is the run time error 9 on the second pass through the loop. It gets hung up on the Evar. It works all the way through if I close the excel file that opens. It seems to not be able to open multiple excel sheets at once. To test I added `ActiveWorkbook.Close` and it ran clean

Comment: In that case see Andy's answer at the post marked as duplicate.

Comment: Tim, I did use andy's response and it worked, however there is now a larger issue. Please see my comment to Mr. Bungle above your post. I have also edited the code above.